# Show error 500 when php fails

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to find how to force php server to throw error 500 when parsing php files fail. The reason is that I use php to build backend service. I can only do it in the .htaccess file.

At this stage my errors are entirely enabled, so when something goes wrong in php I get nice message where is the problem.

How can I disable displaying error and throwing just 500 when there is syntax error in php file ? Most of the cases I tried to find on web deal with opposite problem :D

Answer (score 0):

is this what you need ?

```
function my_error_handler()
  {
   $last_error = error_get_last();
   if ($last_error && $last_error['type']==E_ERROR)
   {
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
    echo '...';//html for 500 page
   }
}
register_shutdown_function('my_error_handler');
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you wanna use `.htaccess` to enable / disable your PHP errors to display.

In `.htaccess` you can set params of php.ini as below.

```
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  /home/path/public_html/domain/PHP_errors.log
```

Basically, `.htaccess` is good idea because it will reflect on your project level not the server level.

Comment: This still displays standard parse error like: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$email' (T_VARIABLE) in /www/htdocs/w0123ddc/mydomian.com/pub/v1/activate on line 19`. I need error 500 in this case

Comment: You can use `ErrorDocument 500 http://example.com/500/` if 500 then it will redirected to the 500 page.

Comment: You can hide parse errors in `.htaccess` by usingn `php_value error_reporting 0`

Comment: Did you check ?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand why should I redirect to some other pages when error occurs. I just simply wants server to throw 500. I didn't know in php this is so difficult to achieve

Comment: Do you have access of your project or just .htaccess ?

Comment: I have access to my project, sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124692/discussion-between-loading-and-sumofighter666).

Comment: The problem is when `php_flag display_errors on` it always return `200`. Making it `php_flag display_errors off` will return 500. This is an answer. Thanks a lot @loading.. for assistance

Comment: That's what I mentioned in the .htaccess how you can hide / show errors.

Comment: don't forget to upvote and accept my answer, it it helped you in a way.